# best type of Array for using the Iterator Pattern

Tags: java, arrays, design-patterns

First let me say that I am quiet new to Java, but not so new.

I am looking to build a restaurant menu application using the iterator pattern.
So my question would be what would be the best array type to implement a 2D array with String name of item, Double Value?

Sample

```
ArrayList<String> menuItems;
 
    public PancakeHouseMenu() {
        menuItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        addItem("K&B's Pancake Breakfast",5);
```

```
String[][] menuItems;
public DinerMenu() {
        menuItems = new String[MAX_ITEMS];
        addItem("Vegetarian BLT",5);
```

or could I use Hashmaps if so what would be the most efficient in code and in runtime.

I am looking for insight into the greater picture for using arrays with the given scenario above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's java. Java is nominally typed. You got a concept? give it a name!

```
class MenuItem {
    String name;
    int price; // in cents
}
```

Then if you want to have a list of these for a menu, then.. have a list of these:

```
List<MenuItem> items;
```

simple as that.
`String[][]` is mostly useless; you can't represent prices in strings and you wouldn't want to, and your code is going to devolve into an unreadable mess. `String` as a type is far less descriptive than `MenuItem` and gives you no opportunity to write all code that would be related to menu items itself inside the MenuItem class which is where it belongs.

NB: YOu do need toString, equals, and hashCode impls on that MenuItem class. You can write them yourself, or have your IDE generate them, or use something like [lombok](https://projectlombok.org), or if you're on java16 and got preview features on, records.

Answer (score 1):

Hashmap would he be more efficient than an array in this case . Hashmaps offer constant time look ups , inserts , and deletes (on average ).

An implementation would look like this

```
HashMap<String, Double> menu  = new HashMap<>();
 menu.put("burger", 5.50);
 menu.containsKey("burger"); //true
 menu.get("burger"); //5.50
```